# Unable to map array of object into jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am adding the jQuery Autocomplete plugin to my project. I have a source value which is an array of objects (from a mySQL database). I am unable to map them into desired format of autocomplete.

This is the data want to map:

```js
[{
  "value": "730",
  "label": "iPhone"
}, {
  "value": "731",
  "label": "Screen Protector"
}, {
  "value": "732",
  "label": "Maxboost"
}, {
  "value": "733",
  "label": "JETech"
}, {
  "value": "734",
  "label": "Mr Shield"
}]
```

```js
$("#product_one").autocomplete({
  source: $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/wp-json/product/product-info/",
    success: function(res) {
      $.each(res, function(key, val) {
        return {
          "label": val.label,
          "value": val.value
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Any suggestion or modification of question would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're providing `source` with a jqXHR object, not an array, string or function as it expects ([docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source))

Given the use of AJAX, it would make the most sense for you to use provide a function which uses the `request` and `response` arguments. Also note that as the data you retrieve is already in the correct format (ie. an array of objects with `label` and `value` properties), you can provide it directly to `response()` without needing to loop through it. Try this:

```js
$("#product_one").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/wp-json/product/product-info/",
      success: function(data) {
        response(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: One more query i have regarding this @Rory McCrossan, i want to display the some output on the change event of autocomplete so, how can i do ?

Comment: If I've understood what you're asking, that should happen by default. If you have a specific issue with how the autocomplete is working, I'd suggest starting a new question

Answer (score 0):

You should first load your data and then set them as the source of the autocomplete.

```
$.ajax({               
      type:"GET",
      url: "/wp-json/product/product-info/",
      success:function(res){

           //Based on your object creation, it looks that you can directly use the response
           $( "#product_one" ).autocomplete(res);   

      }
});
```